# Why are different lengths of nucleotides taken for structure prediction from an miRNA match area after BLAST analysis?

Tags: bioinformatics, structure-prediction, blast, microrna

Generally in miRNA prediction most researchers do as Blast search with a set of miRNAs downloaded from miRBase with the parameters they require. Later on usually custom methods are utilized to get an area around the match area for structure prediction.

In [one paper](http://bioinformatics.oxfordjournals.org/content/21/18/3610.abstract), I found that ~70 flanking nt of match area was taken as pre-miRNA for structural analysis while in [this paper](http://hindawi.com/journals/ijg/2012/957607) ~100 flanking nt of the match area was taken for pre-miRNA structure prediction. Any idea why so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no hard and fast rule for how many nucleotides you have to select. If your miRNA is ~20nt and you take 70nt from both sides (average length of hairpins is ~84nt in humans), your total length will be 160nt. The point of taking $\pm70nt$ is that you don't know if your read is -3p or -5p. So take 70nt from both sides.

The maximum length of a human miRNA hairpin is 180nt for mir-3648 (90nt per half hairpin). In such cases you may take more flanking residues. But these cases are rare.